# Django doesnt render Form

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates

When I request the url in the browser, django does not render the form defined in the forms.py but only the hardcoded html in bulk_import.html.

**bulk_import.html**

```
{% extends 'score/base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}

    <div class="container my-5">
    <h1>Bulk Import</h1>
    <form action="" method=POST>
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form2 }}
        <input type="submit" value="Absenden" class="btn btn-secondary">
    </form>

    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

**forms.py**

```
class BulkModulImport(forms.Form):
    text = forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'rows': '4'})
```

**views.py**

```
def bulk_modul_import(request):
    submitted = False
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = BulkModulImport(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            def remove_dots_and_numbers(text):
                lines = text.split('\n')
                updated_lines = []
                for line in lines:
                    # Use regular expression to remove dots and numbers at the end of each line
                    updated_line = line.replace(' .', '')
                    updated_line = re.sub(r'\s*\d*$', '', updated_line)
                    if "Module der Lehreinheit" not in updated_line:
                        Modul(title=line,proposer=request.user, dozent=None, created_date=timezone.now(), description="").save()
                        updated_lines.append(updated_line)

            remove_dots_and_numbers(form.cleaned_data['text'])

            messages.success(request, ('Du hast erfolgreich einen Bulk-Import der Module durchgeführt!'))
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('modul_list'))
    else:
        form2 = BulkModulImport()
        return render(request, 'score/bulk_import.html', {'form2': form2})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the widget as a form field. I used a `CharField` field and placed a widget in it. After this, the form field is displayed.

```
class BulkModulImport(forms.Form):
    text = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'rows': '4'}))
```

documentation: [widget](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/forms/widgets/)